# f2py not returning out a function, giving free(): invalid next size (normal) error

Tags: python, fortran, f2py

I've not got much experience with Fortran or `f2py`, but I'm using an example a colleague has written to try to write my own.

I have a part of a Python function that I want to be written in Fortran to try and get a good speedup. The Fortran subroutine I have written and will call with `f2py` is

```
    subroutine cone_model_func(box_cart, &
              box_em, box_ne, box_Te, &
              iz_sigma_box, box_bool, pixels, &
              vecs, gas_valve_cart, ll, n_vec, &
              box_base, cone_c, cone_m, dV, N_box, &
              M, iz, pixel_count)

      ! Inputs
      real(8), intent(in) :: box_cart(:,:,:,:) ! (151,151,151,3)
      real(8), intent(in) :: box_em(:,:,:), box_ne(:,:,:), box_Te(:,:,:), iz_sigma_box(:,:,:) ! (151,151,151)
      logical, intent(in) :: box_bool(:,:,:) ! (151,151,151)
      real(8), intent(in) :: pixels(:,:,:), vecs(:,:,:) ! (151,151,3)
      real(8), intent(in) :: gas_valve_cart(3), ll(3), n_vec(3) ! (3)
      real(8), intent(in) :: box_base, cone_c, cone_m, dV
      integer, intent(in) :: N_box
      real(8) :: M(:), iz(:) ! (151)

      ! Local variables
      real(8) :: box_n0(size(box_ne,1),size(box_ne,2),size(box_ne,3)) ! (151,151,151)
      real(8) :: distances(size(pixels,1),size(pixels,2)), plane_perp_dist(size(pixels,1),size(pixels,2)) ! (151,151)
      integer :: inds(2) ! (2)
      real(8) :: mu, sigma_n0
      integer :: i, j, k

      ! Output
      real(8), intent(out) :: pixel_count(size(vecs,1),size(vecs,2)) ! (151,151)

      ! The function
      do i=1, N_box
        if (M(i) > 0.d0) then
          mu = abs(sum((ll + box_base * i * n_vec - gas_valve_cart) * n_vec))
          sigma_n0 = (cone_m * mu + cone_c) * denom
          plane_perp_dist = 0.d0
          box_n0 = 0.d0
          do j=1, N_box
            do k=1, N_box
              plane_perp_dist(j,k) = magnitude1(gas_valve_cart + (mu * n_vec) - box_cart(i,j,k,:))
              box_n0(i,j,k) = neutral_gauss(plane_perp_dist(j,k), M(i), sigma_n0)
              if (box_bool(i,j,k)) then
                distances = distance_to_vector(box_cart(i,j,k,:), vecs, pixels)
                inds = minloc(distances)
                pixel_count(inds(1),inds(2)) = pixel_count(inds(1),inds(2)) + (box_n0(i,j,k)*box_em(i,j,k)*box_ne(i,j,k)*dV)
              end if
            end do
          end do
        else
          M(i) = 0.d0
        end if
        if (i < N_box) then
          iz(i) = sum(box_n0(i,:,:)*vel_Te(box_Te(i,:,:))*iz_sigma_box(i,:,:)*box_ne(i,:,:)*dV*dV)
          M(i+1) = M(i) - iz(i)
        end if
      end do

    end subroutine cone_model_func
```

I can call the function and get it to start running from my Python function, up until the line

```
distances = distance_to_vector(box_cart(i,j,k,:), vecs, pixels)
```

I then get the following error

```
free(): invalid next size (normal)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I know that it gets up to this line because I can put a print statement before it and it prints it out fine. I can also put a print statement in the very last line of the distance_to_vector function, and that prints out too. So there is some issue with how that function is outputting the array I think?

The distance_to_vector function is:

```
    function distance_to_vector(P, v, v0)

      ! Inputs
      real(8), intent(in) :: P(3)
      real(8), intent(in) :: v(:,:,:), v0(:,:,:)

      ! Local variables
      real(8) :: mag(size(v,1),size(v,2))
      real(8) :: mu
      integer :: i, j

      ! Outputs
      real(8) :: distance_to_vector(size(v0,1),size(v0,2))

      ! The function
      mag = 1.d0/(magnitude3(v)**2)
      do i=1, size(v,1)
        do j=1, size(v,2)
          mu = sum((P - v0(i,j,:)) * v(i,j,:)) * mag(i,j)
          distance_to_vector(i,j) = magnitude1((mu * v(i,j,:))+v0(i,j,:)-P)
        end do
      end do
    print*, 'This print statement returns fine'
    ! end and return
    end function distance_to_vector
```

and the two functions `magnitude1` and `magnitude3` that it calls work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am actually very stupid, and have managed to fix this. The error was in the line

```
real(8) :: distances(size(pixels,1),size(pixels,2)), plane_perp_dist(size(pixels,1),size(pixels,2))
```

and I was giving `plane_perp_distance` the wrong sizes to use. This adds up to what I had mostly read online before, about the error I was receiving often referring to an index out of the specified array size, but it was throwing me as I was able to get about 3 or 4 lines past the point that was breaking.

Comment: Excellent! Well sorted out! But note real( 8 ) is not very good practice, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/838310/fortran-90-kind-parameter for why; the selected_real_kind or iso_fortran_env methods are much better

Comment: I'm a little confused by the link you've sent me, but as I said I'm new to fortran and my current code is made from butchering a colleagues example. I'm sure I'll get used to it, but thank you for the additional reading :)

Comment: The essence is Real( 8 ) is not portable, it will work with some compilers, but not with others. It's thus thought to be poor practice. The link outlines ways that will work with all compilers